# How to prevent other user/team member from executing few commands from the root project?

Tags: bash, git, command, command-line-interface

I want to prevent or warn my other team members to execute few commands from the root of the project. I am not sure if it is possible, but I need this to prevent any break in the project.
For eg. We are building an application and in our team, we sync the code using Github, then we make separate branches but we are using amplify for the backend, so I want to prevent my other team members and me also to run few commands like `amplify push` or `amplify pull` or `amplify remove`.

(I know for amplify and AWS services, I can manage IAM roles and policies, but this is not the only single case.)

I am using mac os, and I want a file that can work like .bashrc but for my project, not globally, and we should be able to sync that file with Github remote repo.

Please correct me, if my requirements are not legit.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by making the GitHub repository writeable only by select few users.

Comment: thanks for the response. Yes, we are already using Github, but the thing is I just want to prevent/warn my other team members if they are executing any particular command in the root dir of the project.